# How to add multiple types of cache in CACHES setting in settings.py is django

Tags: django, caching, types

I have a django application.
I want to use both database cache and redis cache at different places in my application.
How do I write the settings in settings.py?

How do I import both redis and database cache in my code and set some data into both types of cache?

I tried this in django settings.py

```
CACHES = {
  'default': {
        
       'BACKEND':'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
       'LOCATION': 'data-caches',
  },

 'Redis': {    
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache',
    'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'db': '1',
        'parser_class': 'redis.connection.PythonParser',
        'pool_class': 'redis.BlockingConnectionPool',
     } 
   }
 }
```

but when I import in my code
from django.core.cache import cache
It always picks the default one.
How do I import database cache in one python file and
redis cache in a different python file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your cache name in the cache module while saving and getting the data from the second cache. like this in your case:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
redis_cache = caches['Redis']
redis_cache.get('key')
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/cache/#accessing-the-cache

Comment: Hi Divya, 
Thanks for the answer. 
But I when I set cache='Redis' in cache.set and get I am getting error   
  self.cache.set(key, value, cache='Redis')
TypeError: DatabaseCache.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cache'
It looks like django is importing database cache which is default setting in the settings.py
that dos not have keyword argument cache.
It should import Redis cache somehow right?
Any ideas?
Thanks again

Comment: Hi @Deepali, I have updated the answer. Can you please try and let me know? I have also updated the documentation link for your reference.

Comment: Thanks Divya, I also saw that documentation after I posted the error. It works.